# magento Url is not working for first time

Tags: magento

when we open a site : http://ab1.domain.com/

for first time in browser, it will redirect to below url

http://ab1.domain.com/://index.php/? & give **404 Not Found 1**

**://index.php/?** is adding as suffix. but if we open 2nd time, than its working fine.

its multi-store site, when we disabled all stores also still problem is there.

It was problem with custom module , we are using this module for displaying respective currency based on country.

**Data.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Atwix
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category    Atwix Mod
 * @package     Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher
 * @author      Atwix Core Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Atwix (http://www.atwix.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Helper/Data.php */
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_STORE = 'India';

    /**
     * countries to store relation
     * default is English
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_countryToStore = array(
        'IN' => 'India',
        'US' => 'USA',
        'FR' => 'France',
        'AR' => 'US dollar [$]',
       // 'BO' => 'US dollar [$]'




    );

    /**
     * get store view name by country
     * @param $country
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getStoreByCountry($country)
    {
        if (isset($this->_countryToStore[$country])) {
            return $this->_countryToStore[$country];
        }
        return self::DEFAULT_STORE;
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                <class>Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Helper</class>
            </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                <class>Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model</class>
            </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                        <class>atwix_ipstoreswitcher/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPostdispatch</method>
                    </atwix_ipstoreswitcher>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
        if ($cookie->get('geoip_processed') != 1) {
            $geoIPCountry = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $countryCode = $geoIPCountry->getCountry();
            if ($countryCode) {
                $storeName = Mage::helper('atwix_ipstoreswitcher')->getStoreByCountry($countryCode);
                if ($storeName) {
                    $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeName, 'name');
                    if ($store->getName() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()) {
                        $event->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($store->getCurrentUrl(false));
                    }
                }
            }
            $cookie->set('geoip_processed', '1', time() + 86400, '/');
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

What i tried is i replaced `$store->getCurrentUrl(false)` by `Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_use_rewrite' => true, '_forced_secure' => true))` than url problem is solved. but module feature is not working.

Comment: Please check all store URL in backend.

Comment: @SunnyRathod but i disabled all stores except main store., can you please guide me where to check store url ?

Comment: `System >> Configuration >> Web >> Unsecure` and `System >> Configuration >> Web >> Secure`
Make you sure that you have select right store at top left corner store switcher dropdown.

Comment: @SunnyRathod under Web , we have `
Use Web Server Rewrites : YES` & Base Url is `http://ab1.collagekingapp.com/` in both secure & unsecure url.

Comment: Use Web Server Rewrites : YES means remove `index.php` in your url. If you turn off then all url come with `index.php`

Comment: @SunnyRathod yes, i tried that , 2nd time index.php is not coming, but 1st time its coming as [here](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/)

Comment: please enter your url at `http://www.wheregoes.com/`. something is wrong in your code or htaccess file.

Comment: @SunnyRathod `This site can’t be reached &  www.sb1.domain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.` i found this when i tried adding `http://www` as prefix.

Comment: @SunnyRathod i updated .htaccess code in qiestion. please check once.

Comment: `http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/` use this url

Comment: @SunnyRathod its redirecting to here : http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/://index.php/?

Comment: @SunnyRathod I just created store views in backend, is it required to do any changes in .htaccess file ? i want to use same url for all store views.

Comment: I means to say only is something is wrong in your code, htaccess or redirect setting.

Comment: @SunnyRathod i posted .htaccess code in question. can you please check if i send backend credentials ?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` please try with this at your htaccess file

Comment: @SunnyRathod when i tried solution gave by IT Experts Solutions [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error)
i got `500 internal server error`

Comment: Yes, implement this solution.

Comment: @SunnyRathod i got 500 internal server error.

Comment: Something is wrong please check server rewrite mode is enable or not and i hope you know how to use `RewriteBase`

Comment: @SunnyRathod it was problem with one of the [extension](https://github.com/vovsky/Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher) , i updated the module code in question , please check. this extension is used for displaying the related currency with respect to the country.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112046/discussion-between-sunny-rathod-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Comment: @SunnyRathod please check the "Edit" section in question.

Comment: Please check with remove one by one parameter. If still not working please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can look(search) for `://index.php/?` in your database and can make changes in database and there you will get an extension name as well from where it comes or from core files.

Comment: Sory i forget to update the question, it was from extension. i posted a code of extension in question.

Comment: can you please check code & help me why its not working for first time.

Comment: You have to debug the code but there might be some issue in function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)

Comment: please check the "Edit" section in question.

Comment: can you try to Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options and set the 'Add Shop Code to URLs' option to Yes,
 with following code as same before: 
$store->getCurrentUrl(false)

Comment: Sorry for Delay. Now everything is fine but `store codes` are adding at the end of the url. I dont want that as like 

[link1](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/usa/apple.html)  & [link2](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/usa/)

Comment: so now you need to find way to remove store codes by any other way if everything working with this...you can try to remove it from htaccess file

Comment: can you please tell what code i need to add or remove from `.htaccess` file to get the solution ?

Comment: Try with this :
Open your .htaccess file

Look for "RewriteEngine on"
Paste these two lines below it:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^indelust.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://indelust.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: i got this error : `You don't have permission to access /var/www/html/sb1/indelust.com/ on this server.` you can check [here](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112294/discussion-between-lalita-patil-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Comment: Now also its displaying store codes , but only for first time in browser. but in 2nd time its not displaying store view code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Atwix
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category    Atwix Mod
 * @package     Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher
 * @author      Atwix Core Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Atwix (http://www.atwix.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
/* app/code/local/Atwix/Ipstoreswitcher/Model/Observer.php */

class Atwix_Ipstoreswitcher_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * redirects customer to store view based on GeoIP
     * @param $event
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatch($event)
    {
        $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
            $cnCode =  $geoIP->getCountry();
       // echo $cnCode='IN';
            switch ($cnCode) {
                case "US": {
                      Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');
                      break;
                }
                case "IN": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                }
                case "CA": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('lca');
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');
                    break;
                }
                echo Mage::app()->getCurrentStore();

        }

    }
}
```